# How to use package manager with deno?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, yarnpkg

I recently got to know about Deno the alternative of NodeJS, I can't find an instruction to use yarn or npm with Deno. Is there any way that yarn or npm can be used with Deno.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Deno doesn't come with a package manager like npm or yarn, you'll have to load the 3rd party packages manually in a file normally called deps.ts. You can find more info here (https://deno.land/manual/examples/manage_dependencies)